# Values are getting stored in different stack even though different variables are used in the code for each stack

Tags: c, input, stack

I wanted to create 4 stacks, 1 for each subject. Then in each stack store number of days left for each assignment to be submitted. This is the code I have written. The code works with the exception of 1 flaw:
When values are stored in one stack they also show up in the other stacks with value 0 and same number of elements for example :
I store values 5,20,7 in the stack of ds exit that stack and  go to the stack of dsgt and store 9,11 and then on printing the values in stack of dsgt the code prints out as " 0 0 0 9 11" here 0 0 0 are the 3 elements of the 1st stack. Now on exiting the stack of dsgt and going back to stack of ds and printing its value the output is "5 7 20 0 0 " , 0 0  here are the elements of the stack of dsgt which I dont want to print with ds and rest of the stacks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 20
int st1[MAXSIZE];
int st2[MAXSIZE];
int st3[MAXSIZE];
int st4[MAXSIZE];
int top = -1;
void push(int st[], int item);
int pop(int st[]);
int peek(int st[]);
void display(int st[]);
void sort(int st[]);

int main() {
    int subj;
    printf("\nEnter the number associated with the Subject assignment that has to be tracked\n");
    int choice = 0, item1;
    do {
            printf("\n 1. Data Structures");
            printf("\n 2. DSGT ");
            printf("\n 3. CG ");
            printf("\n 4. Math");
            printf("\n 5. Exit Code");
            printf("\n Enter Your Choice");
            scanf("%d", & choice);
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                    ds();
                    break;
            case 2:
                    dsgt();
                    break;
            case 3:
                    cg();
                    break;
            case 4:
                    math();
                    break;
            case 5:
                    printf("Exited");
                    break;
            default:
                    printf("\n Wrong Input");
            }
    } while (choice != 5);

    return 0;
}

int dsgt() {
    int choice, item2;
    do {
            printf("Stack Operation \n");
            printf("\n 1. Add A New Assignment");
            printf("\n 2. Remove the latest Completed Assignment ");
            printf("\n 3. View the latest Pending Assignment ");
            printf("\n 4. View All the pending Assignments");
            printf("\n 5. Exit Code");
            printf("\n Enter Your Choice");
            scanf("%d", & choice);
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                    printf("\n Enter the Number of Days Left for the Assignment to be Submitted");
                    scanf("\n %d", & item2);
                    push(st2, item2);
                    sort(st2);
                    break;
            case 2:
                    item2 = pop(st2);
                    printf("\n Removed Assignment is: \n %d", item2);
                    break;
            case 3:
                    item2 = peek(st2);
                    printf("\n The Latest Assignment to be Submitted is:%d", item2);
                    break;
            case 4:
                    display(st2);
                    break;
            case 5:
                    printf("Exited");
                    break;
            default:
                    printf("\n Wrong Input");
            }
    } while (choice != 5);
}

int ds() {
    int choice, item1;
    do {
            printf("Stack Operation \n");
            printf("\n 1. Add A New Assignment");
            printf("\n 2. Remove the latest Completed Assignment ");
            printf("\n 3. View the latest Pending Assignment ");
            printf("\n 4. View All the pending Assignments");
            printf("\n 5. Exit Code");
            printf("\n Enter Your Choice");
            scanf("%d", & choice);
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                    printf("\n Enter the Number of Days Left for the Assignment to be Submitted");
                    scanf("\n %d", & item1);
                    push(st1, item1);
                    sort(st1);
                    break;
            case 2:
                    item1 = pop(st1);
                    printf("\n Removed Assignment is: \n %d", item1);
                    break;
            case 3:
                    item1 = peek(st1);
                    printf("\n The Latest Assignment to be Submitted is:%d", item1);
                    break;
            case 4:
                    display(st1);
                    break;
            case 5:
                    printf("Exited");
                    break;
            default:
                    printf("\n Wrong Input");
            }
    } while (choice != 5);
}

int cg() {
    int choice, item3;
    do {
            printf("Stack Operation \n");
            printf("\n 1. Add A New Assignment");
            printf("\n 2. Remove the latest Completed Assignment ");
            printf("\n 3. View the latest Pending Assignment ");
            printf("\n 4. View All the pending Assignments");
            printf("\n 5. Exit Code");
            printf("\n Enter Your Choice");
            scanf("%d", & choice);
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                    printf("\n Enter the Number of Days Left for the Assignment to be Submitted");
                    scanf("\n %d", & item3);
                    push(st3, item3);
                    sort(st3);
                    break;
            case 2:
                    item3 = pop(st3);
                    printf("\n Removed Assignment is: \n %d", item3);
                    break;
            case 3:
                    item3 = peek(st3);
                    printf("\n The Latest Assignment to be Submitted is:%d", item3);
                    break;
            case 4:
                    display(st3);
                    break;
            case 5:
                    printf("Exited");
                    break;
            default:
                    printf("\n Wrong Input");
            }
    } while (choice != 5);
}

int math() {
    int choice, item4;
    do {
            printf("Stack Operation \n");
            printf("\n 1. Add A New Assignment");
            printf("\n 2. Remove the latest Completed Assignment ");
            printf("\n 3. View the latest Pending Assignment ");
            printf("\n 4. View All the pending Assignments");
            printf("\n 5. Exit Code");
            printf("\n Enter Your Choice");
            scanf("%d", & choice);
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                    printf("\n Enter the Number of Days Left for the Assignment to be Submitted");
                    scanf("\n %d", & item4);
                    push(st4, item4);
                    sort(st4);
                    break;
            case 2:
                    item4 = pop(st4);
                    printf("\n Removed Assignment is: \n %d", item4);
                    break;
            case 3:
                    item4 = peek(st4);
                    printf("\n The Latest Assignment to be Submitted is:%d", item4);
                    break;
            case 4:
                    display(st4);
                    break;
            case 5:
                    printf("Exited");
                    break;
            default:
                    printf("\n Wrong Input");
            }
    } while (choice != 5);
}

void push(int st[], int item) {
    if (top == MAXSIZE - 1) {
            printf("\n You Have a lot of Assignments Due, GET WORKING!!!");
    } else {
            top = top + 1;
            st[top] = item;
    }
}
int pop(int st[]) {
    int item;
    if (top == -1) {
            printf("Great Work No Assignment Are Pending");
            return 0;
    } else {
            item = st[top];
            top = top - 1;
    }
    return item;
}
int peek(int st[]) {
    int item;
    if (top == -1) {
            printf("Great Work No Assignment Are Pending");
            return 0;
    } else {
            item = st[top];
            return item;
    }
}
void display(int st[]) {
    if (top == -1) {
            printf("Great Work No Assignment Are Pending");
    } else {
            for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--) {
                    printf("\n%d\n", st[i]);
            }
    }
}
void sort(int st[]) {
    int tmp, i, j;
    for (int i = top; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (j = i + 1; j <= top; j++) {
                    if (st[i] < st[j]) {
                            tmp = st[j];
                            st[j] = st[i];
                            st[i] = tmp;
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've edited your problem description with the exception of the last sentence.  Can you edit to rephrase the part after _flaw:_,  As is, it is not clear what you are describing.

Comment: yes ill do that

Comment: I have elaborated the flaw with an example so that it is understandable

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I see some issues:  - you don't initialise your stack arrays. - you're using a single global `top` for all stack operations.

Comment: One observation, relevant or not, several functions are prototyped using a return of `int`, but they do not have `return` statements.  eg `int math(void){...}` needs a `return` statement, or if not needed, make the prototype: `void math(void)`

Comment: Initialize this (and the other stacks) to zeros like this: `int st1[MAXSIZE] = {0};`

Comment: There is a lot of code duplication. You ought to factor out the common code.

Comment: `top` is a single global variable.  Yet it seems it is being used to  track contents of all 4 stacks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use a `structure` for your stacks that contains the array and the `top` value e.g.

```
typedef struct{
    int stack[MAXSIZE];
    int top;
}stack_t;
```

Then you can declare your stacks and initialize them:

```
stack_t st1 = {{0}, -1};
stack_t st2 = {{0}, -1};
stack_t st3 = {{0}, -1};
stack_t st4 = {{0}, -1};
```

or place them in an array

```
stack_t stacks[4]={
    {{0}, -1},
    {{0}, -1},
    {{0}, -1},
    {{0}, -1}, };
```

You need to declare your functions as follows and update their implementation accordingly:

```
void push(stack_t* st, int item);
int pop(stack_t* st);
int peek(stack_t st);
void display(stack_t st);
void sort(stack_t* st);
void dsgt(void);
void cg(void);
void math(void);
void ds(void);
```

The `push`, `pop`, `sort` functions then all use pointers to `stack_t` e.g.

```
int pop(stack_t* st) {
    int item =0;
    if (st->top == -1) {
        printf("Great Work No Assignment Are Pending");
    } else {
        item = st->stack[st->top];
        st->top = st->top - 1;
    }
    return item;
}
```

`display` and `peek` function are okay with `stack_t` parameter as they don't change it.

If you place all of your stack structures in an array, you then can use a global variable as an index into your `stack_t` array and reduce the duplication of your choice code.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Chris BD

Comment: Yup the code is working now as intended thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Glad that its sorted. Don't forget to mark answers or give votes.